# How to convert thunderbirds' "address ends with" rule in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, email-filter

I'm going to be forced to move to outlook with company mail.
Now, I love the flexibility of Thunderbird with filtaquilla filters, what I need is a way to express, at least, the "ends with" and the "begins with" filters anyway having regex will be much better.

So, for example, anything coming from `sender:/@stack(exchange|overflow).com$/i` will be matched and moved to `stack-community`

Otherweise at least having two rules one matching `ends with @stackoverflow.com` and  the other matching `ends with @satckexchange.com` could suffice

Answer (score 1):

Outlook does not support "ends with" rules. You will need to learn the VBA
script-language and create a VBA-based rule for doing that.
You're in for a very long haul.

If you're really determined, here are some pointers:

- [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)
  explains how to create the script-based rule.
- [Regular Expression Rules in Outlook 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865500/regular-expression-rules-in-outlook-2007)
- [Move emails where the subject matches a particular RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504274/move-emails-where-the-subject-matches-a-particular-regex)

These will get you started. More precise information can be found
on the internet for each step of your script.

Answer (score 0):

> So, for example, anything coming from sender:/@stack(exchange|overflow).com$/i will be matched and moved to stack-community

For this, we can create a rule in Outlook via File > Info > Manage Rules & Alerts > New Rule as shown in the below figure:

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.